# Error appear when using cron [Scheduler] QueryFailedError: read ECONNRESET

Tags: mysql, cron, nestjs, typeorm

I have an operation to execute at night

```
   @Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_DAY_AT_1AM)
  async setValideFileRemainder() {
    var date = new Date();
    let dateToday = date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
    let remainders =  await this.healthFileRepository.find({
      where: { remainder_date: dateToday }})
    for (let file of remainders) {
      file.is_valide = 1; 
      await this.healthFileRepository.save(file);
    }
  }
```

when I test this function in an endpoint or each 5 min for example it works, but at night it always gives me this error:

```
[Nest] 18728   - 09/15/2021, 7:53:52 AM   [Scheduler] QueryFailedError: read ECONNRESET +38765424ms
```

PS: I'm using MySQL as a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are running into a MySQL connection timeout as your client application is idling. The MySQL server will disconnect your client if there is no activity within the time range configured by [`wait_timeout`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout).

You will either need to:

- tweak your MySQL server configuration and increase `wait_timeout`
- send keep alive queries to your server (eg. `SELECT 1`) in an interval shorter than `wait_timeout`
- handle connection drops gracefully, as they can occur for more reasons that are beyond your application or the SQL server (eg. route drops, link down, packet loss, ...)

Comment: I tried these solutions, thanks, at the end I create an endpoint to make the cron execute call it, it woks properly

Comment: The second solution didn't help me, I tried 1m interval.